# How to stop Select component from realigning

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have a Material UI Select component that is used to select a whole category or an item/items inside that category. But it was made on top of a Select component that realigns itself after a value is chosen. How can i disable this behaviour?

```
import React from "react";
import { makeStyles } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import Input from "@material-ui/core/Input";
import InputLabel from "@material-ui/core/InputLabel";
import MenuItem from "@material-ui/core/MenuItem";
import FormControl from "@material-ui/core/FormControl";
import ListItemText from "@material-ui/core/ListItemText";
import Select from "@material-ui/core/Select";
import Checkbox from "@material-ui/core/Checkbox";

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  formControl: {
    margin: theme.spacing(1),
    width: 150,
    left: 100,
    top: 100
  },
  chips: {
    display: "flex",
    flexWrap: "wrap"
  },
  chip: {
    margin: 2
  },
  noLabel: {
    marginTop: theme.spacing(3)
  }
}));

const MenuProps = {
  PaperProps: {
    style: {
      width: 250,
      height: 350
    }
  }
};

const groups = {
  A: [
    "1",
    "2",
    "3",
  ],
  B: [
    "4",
    "5",
    "6",
  ],
  C: [
    "7",
    "8",
    "9",
  ],
  D: [
    "10",
    "11",
    "12",
  ],
};

export default function KarticaKupiVrstaMultiPC() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [personName, setPersonName] = React.useState([]);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log(personName);
  }, [personName]);

  const handleChange = event => {
    let chunks = [];

    if (event.target.value && event.target.value.length === 1) {
      chunks = event.target.value[0].split("-");
    } else if (event.target.value && event.target.value.length > 1) {
      chunks = event.target.value[event.target.value.length - 1].split("-");
    }

    if (chunks[0] === "Select" && chunks[1] === "All") {
      let groupName = chunks[chunks.length - 1];

      let names = [...personName];
      let allSelected = true;

      for (let name of groups[groupName]) {
        if (names.indexOf(name) < 0) {
          allSelected = false;
          break;
        }
      }

      for (let name of groups[groupName]) {
        if (names.indexOf(name) >= 0) {
          names.splice(names.indexOf(name), 1);
        }
      }

      if (!allSelected) {
        names = [...names, ...groups[groupName]];
      }

      setPersonName(names);
    } else {
      setPersonName(event.target.value);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
<FormControl variant="outlined" className={classes.formControl}>
        <InputLabel id="demo-mutiple-checkbox-label">Choose</InputLabel>
        <Select
          labelId="demo-mutiple-checkbox-label"
          id="demo-mutiple-checkbox"
          multiple
          value={personName}
          onChange={handleChange}
          renderValue={selected => selected.join(", ")}
          MenuProps={MenuProps}
          label="Izberi vrsto"
          //input={<Input />}
        >


          {Object.keys(groups).map(key => {
            let list = groups[key].map(individual => {
              return (
                <MenuItem key={individual} value={individual}>
                  <Checkbox checked={personName.indexOf(individual) > -1} />
                  <ListItemText primary={individual} />
                </MenuItem>
              );
            });

            list.unshift(
              <MenuItem key={key} value={`Select-All-${key}`}>
                <ListItemText primary={key} secondary="Select All/None" />
              </MenuItem>
            );

            return list;
          })}
        </Select>
      </FormControl>
    </div>
  );
}
```

//top and left style properties are only there so u can see the problem
https://codesandbox.io/s/gracious-voice-8qr6m

Answer (score 0):

Remove `top` property from `formControl` stylesheet.

Comment: Sadly i had to put those there because otherwise u cannot see the problem as the otherwise the List has no way of moving and realigning anyways.